# How to set dynamic waterfall steps in Bot framework v4(.net core)?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have bot in v3(.net framework) for multiple intent and every intent having different set of questions/steps. There I am using 'PromptOption. choice' for showing dynamic set of questions/steps and taking answer from 'resume' method. added code below.

`PromptDialog.Choice( context: context, **resume: ResumeAfterPromptAnswer, options: promptData.Choices**, prompt: promptData.Text, retry: BotConstants.InvalidSelection, attempts: 2, promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto );`

Now I am trying to migrate my bot to v4 but I am not getting such prompt functionality in V4. just having option for waterfall steps but not able to add steps dynamicaly.
If you have any solution please post it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do is entirely possible in v4. I recommend checking out these community extensions, since they offer some v3-ish functions in v4:

- [Bot Builder ChoiceFlow](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.ChoiceFlow) (I think this is what you're looking for)
- [Bot Builder v4 FormFlow](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow)

Alternatively, you could use the vanilla v4 SDK and [Create advanced conversation flow using branches and loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). The [Complex Dialog Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/43.complex-dialog) is a pretty good example of how to do this.

All that being said, I don't 100% understand what you're asking. If this doesn't address your question, please provide an example conversation flow and I can adjust my answer.

Comment: OP is asking how to generate the waterfall steps at runtime.. I also have this question. Is this even possible?